# Logging firebase warnings

Tags: node.js, logging, firebase-admin

I am getting the following warning on the console of my nodejs app:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials for the app
>   named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid. This usually indicates your app was not
>   initialized correctly. Make sure the "credential" property provided to
>   initializeApp() is authorized to access the specified "databaseURL"
>   and is from the correct project.

Is there a way to send this kind of warnings to a logger?
I don't find nothing of the kind for nodeJs Admin SDK

Just to make absolutely clear, i am not concert with the error itself, only how to log all relevant problems, occurred on my code or on the library code, into one single file that i can look at.

Also, the warning is not possible to log by the api caller because it is not send it back to the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a custom log function via [`admin.database().enableLogging()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database#.enableLogging). See the examples in the reference docs.